# Calling an event handler within a function in React

Tags: reactjs, function, events, ecmascript-6, callback

I'm displaying a dropdown select menuitem that displays a list of vitamins, but I want it to update to the new vitamin that the user selected.

I've tried

```
renderData(handleChange) {
const {vitamins} = this.state.data;
return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
  return (
    <option value="" key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
  )
})
}
```

This one doesn't change the state.

and

```
renderData() {
this.handleChange();
const {vitamins} = this.state.data;
return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
  return (
    <option value="" key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
  )
})
```

}

This one returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined.

Here is my full code:

```
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    value: '',
   data: data.nutrients,
 };

 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({
   value: e.target.value,
  });
}

renderData() {
  this.handleChange();
  const {vitamins} = this.state.data;
  return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
    return (
     <option value="" key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
    )
 })
 }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label className="nutrient-label">
      Vitamins
      <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.renderData()}
      </select>
    </label>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your error is because you're calling `handleChange` inside `renderData` but you're not passing `e` to `handleChange`. So it cannot read target of undefined

Comment: @BrettEast I am not speaking about the `onClick` handler. The one inside it will work fine. Look inside the `renderData` function. That function is calling `handleChange`. How do you pass the `e` from `renderData` to `handleChange`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you go..  Hope this helps :)

class SelectOptionComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            data: [{
                label: 'Vitamin A', value: 'vitaminA'
            }, {
                label: 'Vitamin B', value: 'vitaminB'
            }, {
                label: 'Vitamin C', value: 'vitaminC'
            }],
        };
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        this.setState({
            value: value
        });

        console.log('Selected Item', value)
    }

    renderData() {
        return this.state.data.map((item, index) =>{
            return <option value={item.value} key={index}>{item.label}</option>
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {this.renderData()}
            </select>
        );
    }
}

export default SelectOptionComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code that are likely causing issues:

```
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    value: '',
   data: data.nutrients, // where is this coming from, you have no nutrients
   // I think this should be `data: vitamins` because you access it later
 };

 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

handleChange(e) { // try using the setState function
  this.setState({
   value: e.target.value,
  });
}

// I would write like this:
handleChange(e) {
  const value = e.target.value
  this.setState(() => ({
   value
  }));
}

renderData() {
  this.handleChange(); // remove this line, you don't want to call this function here, and this function needs an argument
  const {vitamins} = this.state.data; // this is where you want vitamins again, not nutrients like you have set in the constructor
  return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
    return (
     <option value="" key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
    )
 })
 }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label className="nutrient-label">
      Vitamins
      <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.renderData()}
      </select>
    </label>
  </form>
)
```

This will potentially do it, hard to check without running it, but removing that call to the `handleChange` function in `renderData()` will help, and watching the names of your data 'vitamins'/'nutrients' will help